# Xamarin iOS - How to debug a background service

Tags: ios, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.ios, cllocationmanager

I am building an app that uses the location services which will start the app when it is in the terminated state using the `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`.  I would like to attach the **Xamarin Studio** debugger to the process when it starts in the background but it doesn't seem possible in Xamarin Studios.  It is easy to attach the debugger and run the application, and even debug in the background, but when the app is terminated, so is the debugging session.  I can't find a way to **attach the Xamarin Studios debugger to the process that starts when a location update is recieved**

My question is the exact same at this, but I want to do that is Xamarin: [How do I debug an iPhone app that's supposed to be launched by location services, into the background, from a terminated state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848629/how-do-i-debug-an-iphone-app-thats-supposed-to-be-launched-by-location-services)

Is there any good way to do this?

Thank you for the help